# Optimizing code that calculates sum of largest sequence of decreasing odd ints

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I wrote a method that does return sum of decreasing sequence.

For example:
if sequence is 13 9 7 12 13 15, then sum is 29 (13 + 9 + 7).

Now I want to optimize it. Cause the same code is repeating muliple times. But I don't now how. Maybe someone can help me?

```
            int sumMax = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (array[i] % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        sum += array[i];

                        if (sumMax < sum)
                        {
                            sumMax = sum;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        sum = 0;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if (sum != 0)
                        {
                            if (array[i - 1] > array[i])
                            {
                                sum += array[i];

                                if (sumMax < sum)
                                {
                                    sumMax = sum;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sum += array[i];

                            if (sumMax < sum)
                            {
                                sumMax = sum;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }

            return sumMax;
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a fairly simple problem. Could simply loop over the array and keep track of the current count and current max value no?

```
var values = new int[] {13, 9 ,7 ,12 ,13, 15};
var max = Int32.MaxValue;
var total = 0;
foreach (int value in values){
    if(value >= max)continue;
    max = value;
    total += value;
}
```

This loops over every element in the array so is O(n), might be some way to make this look nicer using LINQ?

Comment: For a sequence of 1, 5, 3 your code will output 1 and it should be 8.  You don't look for the subsequence of decreasing values with the largest sum, you only look at subsequences starting at the beginning of the sequence, and you don't consider even numbers to break the sequence.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misread what he said, I thought he just wanted to total all the numbers that decrease

Answer (score -1):

I misread what he was asking, something like this would work instead would it not?

```
var values = new int[] {13, 9 ,7 ,12 ,13, 15};
int previous = int.MaxValue;
var total = 0;
var max = 0;
foreach(int value in values){
    if(value >= previous){
        if(total > max) max = total;
        total = 0;
    }
    total += value;
    previous = value;
}
if(total > max) max = total;

Console.WriteLine(max);
```

You can still probabbly make this look nicer with some LINQ, but performance wise its still O(n)